# I am getting no handler found exception even though I am using Controller annotation

Tags: spring-mvc

After initializing the bean, I am getting an exception as handler not found but I am using a controller annotation.

```
May 28, 2019 4:04:57 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: Completed initialization in 836 ms
May 28, 2019 4:04:57 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping for GET /SpringMVCProjectTutorial09/
May 28, 2019 4:05:04 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping for GET /SpringMVCProjectTutorial09/welcome
```

java file

```
    package com.maddus.program;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
@Controller

public class WelcomeToSpringMVCController  {
    @RequestMapping(value="/welcome")   
    public ModelAndView DisplayMessage() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("WelcomeNote");
        model.addObject("msg", "Hello Maddu....\nWelcome to Spring MVC");
        return model;
    }
}
```

spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.maddus.program.WelcomeToSpringMVCController" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">
<display-name>SpringMVCProjectTutorial09</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name><servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Do requests to  `/welcome`  without "SpringMVCProjectTutorial09" work?

Comment: base-package expects a package. `com.maddus.program.WelcomeToSpringMVCController` is not a package.

Comment: yes I removed class name, it solved the issue